# Android Studio on MAC and Finder cmd+shift+F conflict

Tags: macos, android-studio, finder, apple-m2

as the title I was able to use the cmd + shift + F combination for searching in files in Android Studio running on Mac with no issues. From some time to now I still have the finder that came up with their "search" in files and folders.

I think the issue is in Android Studio or in some configuration that changed at some point from any system update or software update.

If I run these shortcut in Chrome for example or some other programs (when Chrome is primarily selected) the finder stay at their place and does not interfere.

Any of you with the same issue? (I know that you are there)
Any of you that found a proper way to address that? And no, changing the search shortcut in Android Studio is not a solution...

My system is Mac Pro 16' M2 - Sonoma 14.1.2 and Android Studio Version is "Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1"